# How to cut off overflow on the left side

Tags: html, css, overflow

I can cut off the overflowed content on the right side, as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{width:50px; background: red; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;}
```

**Result**

[image: cut off on the right side]

How can I cut it off on the left side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change the direction of the text to *right-to-left* by `direction: rtl;`

```css
div {
  width:50px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wusoguro/1/edit)**.

I should note that by changing the `direction`, the exclamation mark of `Hello World!` will go to the left as `!Hello world`.

In order to fix that, you could wrap the text by [`<bdi>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdi) element as follows:

```
<div>
   <bdi>Hello World!</bdi>
</div>
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wusoguro/2/edit)**.

Or use [`unicode-bidi: isolate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) on a `<span>` element (for [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi#Browser_compatibility) web browsers)

Comment: @sawa I just added more details to fix the rtl direction issue you might want to consider that.

Answer (score 3):

Just set direction property to rtl:

```
div{
    direction:rtl;
    width:50px;
    background: red; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5Hj3Q/