# text-align for input tag

Tags: html, css

I use the following code to align the content of an input text field:

```
Path <input type="text" value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions" style="text-align: right;">
```

**Problem:**
This does not work in the case of a long text.

Since I am displaying a folder path, I am interested in displaying the last folder.
I went through many posts posts related to text alignment, but they all advise to use "text-align: right".

Comment: can you fiddle it please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the `direction` of the text input to `rtl` so that it would show the last part of the path.

For further info, refer to my answer to a similar question here:

- [How to cut off overflow on the left side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126759/how-to-cut-off-overflow-on-the-left-side/22126773#22126773)

```css
input[type="text"] {
  /* text-align: right; */
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
Path <input type="text" value="https://stackoverflow.com/questions">
```

Comment: @downvoter, Care to comment? I don't think so. The OP has tagged only `html` and `css` in the question, and the only possible CSS solution gets downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The `rtl` hack is nice, but makes it hard if you actually want to change the value. And if you don't want that, why make it an `input` in the first place?

So alternatively, you can set the cursor at the end of the input using a piece of Javascript:

```js
// Wrap it in a function, if you like.
function selectEnd(input) {
    var pos = input.value.length;
    input.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    input.blur(); // Switch from not focus..
    input.focus(); // .. to focus, to force the cursor into view.
}

// Call it for your input.
selectEnd(document.getElementById('path'));
```

```html
Path <input id="path" type="text" value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions" style="text-align: right;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this,add this attribute only to this tag `dir="rtl"`

```
<input type="text" value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions" dir="rtl">
```

Comment: Why downvoted? Its working. Only no need of `text-align` here